# How to get a value in a database and display on django form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a **DuesLevy** model with a field called **user** which happen to be a foreign key to my **User** model. I want to display email value from the User model to my form **AddMemberDuesForm()**

The reason is this I want to get the email and amount value and pass it to my payment processor.
I am using class based views to process my form below is my code
**forms.py**

```
class AddMemberDuesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class_of_dues = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.Select(choices=options.CLASS_OF_DUES, attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    payment_circle = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.Select(choices=options.PAYMENT_CIRCLE, attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    payment_option = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.Select(choices=options.PAYMENT_OPTION, attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    payment_channel = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.Select(choices=options.PAYMENT_CHANNEL_TYPE, attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    amount = forms.DecimalField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    payment_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'type':'date'}))
    
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))


    class Meta():
        model = DuesLevy
        exclude = ('date_recorded', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'transaction_id')
```

**views.py**

```
class AddMemberDues(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = '/backoffice/'
    model = DuesLevy
    template_name =  'dashboard/add-edit-member-dues.html'
    form_class = AddMemberDuesForm
    context_object_name = 'member_form'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       form = AddMemberDuesForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           form = AddMemberDuesForm()
           form.user.email = form.user.cleaned_data['email']
           self.template_name = 'dashboard/payment.html'
           form.save()
           return render(request,  self.template_name,
            {'email': form.cleaned_data['email'], 'amount': form.cleaned_data['amount']}) 

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        initial = {'email':request.user.email}
        form = AddMemberDuesForm(initial=initial)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'email': form.cleaned_data['email']})
```

I get this error in the

```
'AddMemberDuesForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Internal Server Error: /backoffice/add-member-dues/                                       
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                        
  File "C:\Users\Benedict\Miniconda3\envs\mycda\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner                                                             
    response = get_response(request)                                                      
  File "C:\Users\Benedict\Miniconda3\envs\mycda\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response                                                         
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)                           
  File "C:\Users\Benedict\Miniconda3\envs\mycda\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response                                                         
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)               
  File "C:\Users\Benedict\Miniconda3\envs\mycda\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view                                                                   
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)                                        
  File "C:\Users\Benedict\Miniconda3\envs\mycda\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py", line 52, in dispatch                                                              
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)                                     
  File "C:\Users\Benedict\Miniconda3\envs\mycda\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch                                                               
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)                                              
  File "D:\mycda\backend\views.py", line 348, in get                                      
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'email': form.cleaned_data['email']})     
AttributeError: 'AddMemberDuesForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'
```

Comment: you have initialized another form inside `form.is_valid` if block. Maybe you should name it something else.

Comment: @Ejaz done but didn't work

Comment: are you getting the same error?

Comment: `cleaned_data` is set after `form.is_valid()` is called. You're trying to access `cleaned_data` in `get()` where the form validation does not occur

Comment: I have removed this form = AddMemberDuesForm() form.is_valid() still having the same error

Comment: Please read your traceback. The error happens in `get()`. You are calling `cleaned_data` there. `cleaned_data` exists only after `form.is_valid()` is called. You dont do that in `get(),` which is why `cleaned_data` does not exist there which is why you are getting your error.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko so what do I do and how will my code be ?

Answer (score 0):

It would help to have a look at the code in models.py. Have you got a function get cleaned_data() there?